# Software to handle 100/1000 hours video?

Tags: software

There is some project that will be 720 hours long http://www.thelongestfilm.com/ what software can handle such amount of hours in timeline? Maximum what I could find is final cut pro x - 558 Day Timeline. On Windows every major application like premiere pro or avidemux can handle only 24 hours. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading about [FCP's 1600 track, 558 day long sequence test](http://nofilmschool.com/2014/03/1600-tracks-558-day-timeline-maxing-out-fcpx-on-new-mac-pro) I don't think that's the limit of the software, but the hardware: "...very large numbers of clips within [FCPX](http://www.apple.com/final-cut-pro/) will slow the machine down."

Same is true of Adobe's [Premiere](http://www.adobe.com/products/premiere.html) - as the project grows, the performance lags. [Avid Media Composer](http://www.avid.com/media-composer) manages media differently and AFAIK, there's no limit (?) to the sequence length, but in the comments of the FCP 558days/1600track article, someone writes, "Last time I built a sequence over 13 hours, Avid stopped playing audio." Again, that might be a hardware and/or configuration issue.

Possibly Sony's [Vegas](http://www.vegascreativesoftware.com/) would also be a contender?

Not sure about [Blackmagic Design's DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) or EditShare's [LightWorks](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_lwks&view=download&Itemid=206) (both free).

------EDIT
After talking to some Avid editors, I think I may be wrong and that Avid doesn't like projects even 24hr long, more like a 12-18 hour limit. Not a lot of day long content getting made for broadcast I suppose!

------EDIT
Interesting - & so much for what I think I know - Avid's sequence length maximum is comparatively quite limited. From a friend, "At 48KHz, about 12 hours. **The limit is 2,147,483,648 audio samples.** Six hours if you work at 96KHz."

------EDIT
Don't have an Avid setup to test on, but of note, I understand that if you remove audio tracks, Avid sequences can be much longer. This may hold true for other editing applications & worth testing if you only need 100 or 1000 hours of just "video" and no audio.

Comment: LightWorks - looks like it works, but too customize project video size I need pro. For other heads ups - very big thank you!

Comment: @PavelVanchugov, ah yes... there are some limitations to the freeware... Tried Resolve? Also, I believe [Avid has a 30 day free trial](http://connect.avid.com/media-composer-trial.html)

Comment: @PavelVanchugov, it's a 3D app but has some basic 2D editing: https://www.blender.org/

Comment: vegas pro is 10 hr or something max, blender is 300 000 frames, but it could be rebuild with more. I will try.

Comment: @mr-kennedy blender did it, but some code needs to be edited and rebuild. Avid was too hard for me, I couldn't understand a thing, and it had limits, that you told previously. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PavelVanchugov very glad to hear you found a solution, I would love to know how you did it if you feel like sharing :)

Comment: @mr-kennedy sure:) http://blog.machinimatrix.org/building-blender/ and after step 3, edit "maxframe" in blender\release\scripts\addons\io_shape_mdd\__init__.py

Comment: @PavelVanchugov nice - thanks! (I'm a Blender newB) What's the project you are working on?

Comment: @mr-kennedy It's not interesting, so let's just say I was curious.

Comment: @PavelVanchugov there's a lot to be said for curiosity :)